# echo results of SELECT CONCAT query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

So, I'm trying to get a SELECT CONCAT query to run, return the results of the query and basically display them on a .php webpage. For example, if I manually put the following SQL code into PHPMyAdmin:

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' - ', p.Price)
FROM phones p
JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
JOIN operatingsystem o
ON p.OSID = o.OSID
```

PHPMyAdmin runs it and displays "Apple iPhone 5 - 16GB - iOS - 499.99. However, I am trying to get this to display on a .php page instead of just through PHPMyAdmin and can't get it to work. I'm guessing I need to use some sort of echo command but when I use for example echo $result, it either displays nothing at all on the webpage or sometimes "Resource id #3". My whole PHP code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Phones | Mobiles Four You</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"> 
<div id"header"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></div>
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a id=”nav-home” class=”first” href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a id=”nav-phones” href="phones.php?sort=Make">Phones</a></li>
<li><a id=”nav-search” href="search.php">Search</a></li>
<li><a id=”nav-login” href="login.php">Login</a></li>
<li><a id=”nav-contact” class=”last” href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<h1>Mobile Phones</h1>
</div>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("b*********", "*****", "*****");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: '  . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("bg29li", $con);
$query = ("SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' -             ', p.Price)
FROM phones p
JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
JOIN operatingsystem o
ON p.OSID = o.OSID"); 

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be at all appreciated

Comment: What's the huge gap after 0.Name about? Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: when using select CONTACT() use an alias like contact(blahblah) as shortname then you can get it easily

Comment: I can't see the $result variable on your code, or where are you calling the $query string.

Answer (score 1):

Give the concatenated names an alias, then loop through the rows and echo them:

```
mysql_select_db("bg29li", $con);
$query = ("SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' -             ', '£' , p.Price) AS Names
FROM phones p
JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
JOIN operatingsystem o
ON p.OSID = o.OSID"); 

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // here you can get the values using $row['names']
    echo $row['names'];

} 

mysql_close($con);
```

But, please stop using the mysql_query extensions and use the PDO or prepared statements instead.

Comment: @user1762928 Ensure that you added an alias  `AS names` in `SELECT CONCAT( ... ) AS names` in your query. Can you please show me the exact query you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' -             ', p.Price)  AS val
FROM phones p
JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
JOIN operatingsystem o
ON p.OSID = o.OSID"; 

$res  = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated use mysqli or PDO

Comment: write a if condition in while loop `if($row['val'] == "something"){$requ = $row['val'];}`

Comment: change the query like this and try, but i am not sure about working `$query = "SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' -  &pound;', p.Price)  AS val`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_select_db("bg29li", $con);

First create sql query to run in string format

$query = "SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' -             ', p.Price)
FROM phones p
JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
JOIN operatingsystem o
ON p.OSID = o.OSID";

after that run this query and you will get result in $result variable

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

```
printf("%s  ", $row[0]);
```

}

Comment: it will not give you result

Comment: you need to use mysql_fetch_*

Comment: jay fetching results is required

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = ("SELECT CONCAT(m.Name, ' ', p.Model, ' - ', p.StorageSize, ' - ', o.Name, ' -             ', p.Price)
FROM phones p
JOIN manufacturer m
ON p.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID
JOIN operatingsystem o
ON p.OSID = o.OSID");
```

this wont be enough the `mysql_query($query)` need to be executed else its only a string variable then the either you will have to use the mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_object to get the results